# Make tags in "Top Tags" section of a user profile links (in android app)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

When viewing a user profile for a particular site there is a list of "Top Posts" followed by "Top Tags".

Clicking something in the lists of posts takes you to a post while the tags in "Top Tags" are not clickable.

The tags list on the web based version are clickable and take you to a list of questions with that tag.

Incase this does work on other devices. I am on a Nexus 5, 4.4.2

Comment: Not just you. Same on my 4.2.2 gNexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe I missed this! It's implemented in version 0.1.87 coming out in the next couple hours, thanks!